# abigen error : Failed to generate ABI binding: unsupported arg type: tuple

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, dapp-development

Hello I 'am trying to generate Go ethereum binding for a smart contract in which I have a function that takes a struct as argument.
It seems that abigen doesn'tsupport this argument.

```
struct Device
{
    bytes16 UUID;
    bytes16 hardware_UUID;
    string phone_Number;
}

function SaveDevice(Device memory device) public returns (bool)

{
    Device_Table[device.UUID]=device;
    Device_HardTable[device.hardware_UUID]=device;
}
```

Is there any ssolution for this problem?

Comment: A public function cannot take a struct as input. Pass the struct fields instead.

Comment: Can it return a struct?

Comment: No.......................

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass struct as function parameter and function cannot return struct, but you can pass struct parameters as function parameters and function can return struct parameters. The following code might help you:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

contract DeviceContract {
    struct Device {
        bytes16 hardware_UUID;
        string phone_Number;
    }

    mapping (bytes16 => Device) list_with_devices; 

    function saveDevice(bytes16 _UUID, bytes16 _hardware_UUID, string memory _phone_Number) public returns (bool)  {
        list_with_devices[_UUID] = Device(_hardware_UUID, _phone_Number);
    }

    function getDevice(bytes16 _UUID) public view returns(bytes16, string memory) {
        return (list_with_devices[_UUID].hardware_UUID, list_with_devices[_UUID].phone_Number);
    }
}
```

Comment: can we return a table instead of struct?